# Play store missing & cant update Whatsapp

Tags: google-play-store

I'm using Xiaomi 1s. After updated to MIUI 7, my google play store is not there. And so I cant able to update my Whatasapp. Please help me to update Whatsapp...

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Check the "Unknown Sources" option in the Security Menu in Settings, go to http://pluto.androidapksfree.com/boa/com.android.vending_v6.3.16.B-all-[0]-2697688-80631600_Android-4.0.apk. Your phone will automatically start downloading Google Play Store. After the Play Store is downloaded, install it and update your Whatsapp.
2. Go to https://www.whatsapp.com/android/ and download the latest version of Whatsapp there.

Comment: Must ensure that "Unknown Sources" is checked under the Security menu in Settings.

Comment: While I enjoy playing with apps from unknown sources, I don't recommend to download a core app such as the Play Store from an untrusted website. You may be interested in opengapps.org, instead.